# binance api sell

Tags: php, api, curl

дубль можно удалить
`'symbol=BTCUSDT&side=SELL&type=MARKET&orderId=2705486499&recvWindow=5000&timestamp='.(time() * 1000);`
выдаёт ошибку:

```
Array
(
    [code] => -1102
    [msg] => A mandatory parameter was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.
)
```

Comment: у меня та же проблема, не решили данный вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

У вас не хватает ещё ключа `signature`, добавьте `&signature=<ваши данные>`.